# Immoveable VHDX files on Shared Cluster Volume

Tags: windows, windows-cluster, cluster-shared-volumes

Some time back I created 2x VHDX files to attach later to Virtual Machines.

When I tried to add the disks today, I got an error stating the files are in use by another process.

[image]

I also cannot delete the files. Not from a remote session nor directly from the host.

I tried using handle tool to see where it may be stuck, also used Task Manager > Performance > Resource Monitor > CPU > Associated Handles

These files just do not seem to be listed anywhere. There are no results searching for the file.

So next I tried the Remove-Item -FilePath -Force command, same error and no joy.
[image]

Most other free tools need an absolute file path to trace the handles and the hosts are loaded with Server Core, so no GUI for freeware tools.

And yes, I did try ye olde Reboot procedure. Unless these resources are tied on another host? There are 3 nodes accessing the shared volume.

I will appreciate any pointers into getting rid of these files as they just consume 400GB of space now.

Comment: Are your disks mounted, maybe?

Comment: Hi, no. They were just created. The VM wasn't even spun up yet. So, if they are mounted somehow, how would I check?

Comment: You can view your mounted disks in `diskmgmt.msc`